# R factoring the same categorical variable in two different levels

Tags: r

I seem to have a problem using my categorical variables. I have the same word, say "a", in a pretty small dataset. R however chooses to make two levels of "a" with each their own unique number of observations. If I use summary(data). I get for instance ( for 10 unique observations and categorical variables a,b,c)

```
summary(data)
a:2
a:4
b:2
c:2
```

How do I fix this problem? I tried as.factor(data$categorical_variable) and converting to Excel and back to csv. Thanks.

Comment: May be check for trailing/leading spaces, `summary(trimws(data))`

Comment: We cannot know what is wrong with the information that you provided.  Please provide a sample of your data by typing `dput(head(data, 20))` and pasting the results into your question. Also,  please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: That seems to work akrun, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Glad that @akrun was able to help. In the future, if you are importing other datasets, you might consider trying the following packages and functions to remove whitespaces when you import your data.

I like to use the package `readr` (imported automatically if you end up using the `tidyverse` library) and its function `read_csv`, which automatically strips leading and trailing spaces so that you don't have to. It also does not assume your character fields are factors, and I prefer that default behavior over base R's `read.csv`.

If you are importing excel files, you can use the library `readxl` and its function `read_excel`, which also strips leading and trailing spaces.

Good luck!